# Async Operation for Location return

Tags: android, kotlin

I've the below code to return location, but apparently the return is executed before the location be returned, how can I postpone it to ensure it return at the correct time:

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Context
import android.location.Location
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import oryx.tecna.locateme.extensons.toast

private lateinit var fusedLocationClient: FusedLocationProviderClient

object UtilLocation {
    private lateinit var l : Location

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getLocation(context: Context) : Location{
        context.toast("mlocation is called")
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                    this.l = location!!
                  //  context.toast("my location is: ${location?.latitude}")
                }
       return this.l
    }
}
```

Comment: `fusedLocationClient.lastLocation` is asynchronous, so it can take an indefinite amount to time to complete. So I'm pretty certain that return always will be executed before `this.l = location!!`. That being said, you probably need to change the way the variable is accessed and start relying on the `successListener`. Or you might want to take a look at implementing this with courotines.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> apparently the return is executed before the location be returned

Yes. In this scenario, in kotlin specifically, you can define a [higher-order function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#higher-order-functions). That is a function that takes a function as a parameter. You do this so the location listener can invoke that function when the location is retrieved. The code that calls this `getLocation` function will be able to define what to do when that function (the one passed as parameter) is invoked.

You can also remove the return type and value, because the information will be passed through the function now. It looks like this. Note the 2nd parameter of `getLocation` and the call to `callback.invoke(this.l)`

```
object UtilLocation {
    private lateinit var l : Location

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    fun getLocation(context: Context, callback: (Location) -> Unit) {
        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context!!)

        fusedLocationClient.lastLocation
                .addOnSuccessListener { location : Location? ->
                    this.l = location!!
                    //  context.toast("my location is: ${location?.latitude}")
                    callback.invoke(this.l)
                }
    }
}
```

Then you call it like this

```
UtilLocation.getLocation(context, { location ->
    Log.d("tag", "got location")
})
```

or, [because the last parameter is a function](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter), you can do it like this if you prefer

```
UtilLocation.getLocation(context) { location ->
    Log.d("tag", "got location")
}
```

Comment: What if I want to get a response of the on response failed to return the location, can I do something here, or check in the original function

Comment: @HasanAYousef you can pass in a separate function and have 2 callbacks, 1 for success and 1 for error